# Same function signature but different arguments

Tags: python

```
class BaseClass:
      @abstractmethod
       def example(self, param1, param2, param3=None):

class ConcreteA(BaseClass):    
      def example(self, param1, param2, param3):
          return True

class ConcreteB(BaseClass):
      def example(self, param1, param2):
          return False
```

I am using this as:

```
obj = self.fetch_obj()
obj.example(param1, param2, param3)
```

But the issue is that param3 is not implemented in `ConcreteB`.. so.. if `obj` is `ConcreteB`, then I get an error.
Is there a way to "overload" function definition ignore param3 if it is of 
`ConcreteB` class? How do I make param3 truly optional in Abstract class and get it reflected in the implementations of those class?

Not sure if this is making sense?

Comment: I think it's just easier to add param3 to ConcreteB with a default value and ignore it, right?

Comment: I know what you’re saying from C++ and such but in Python is not like that. In order to implement this in Python is by using `*args` and `**kwargs` type arguments. It’s not the same but it’s doable.

Comment: When you are *using* the objects it could be either and you won't know in advance? And you always want to pass three arguments? And the third argument is NOT optional for `ConcreteA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense!

There are some ways to do it, one of them making the `param3` optional setting it such as `param3 = None`, but it's not a Pythonic way.

The Pythonic way to do it is using the `*args` and `**kwargs` concept, let me show you some examples!

By `*args` examples:

```
#ex1:
def world_cup_titles(country, *args):
    print('Country: ', country)
    for title in args:
        print('year: ', title)

world_cup_titles('Brasil', '1958', '1962', '1970', '1994', '2002')

#ex2:
def build_tuple(*args):
    return args

message_tuple = build_tuple("hello", "planet", "earth", "take", "me", "to", "your", "leader")
print("Tipo: {} || Tupla: {}".format(type(message_tuple), message_tuple))
```

By **kwargs example:

```
def calculate_price(value, **kwargs):
    tax_percentage = kwargs.get('tax_percentage')
    discount = kwargs.get('discount')

    if tax_percentage:
        value += value * (tax_percentage / 100)
    if discount:
        value -= discount

    return value

v1 = calculate_price(100)
print(v1)

v2 = calculate_price(10, discount=5.0)
print(v2 )

v3 = calculate_price(10, discount=5.0, tax_percentage=7)
print(v3)
```

So as you can see sounds more Pythonic, actually it's really easy!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of..:

```
class ConcreteB(BaseClass):


      def example(self, param1, param2):
          """ (docstring) """
          #   [...] (user code)
          return False
```

... use:

```
class ConcreteB(BaseClass):


      def example(self, param1, param2, param3=None):
          """ (docstring) """
          if param3 is not None:
              raise TypeError('Illegal call')
          #   [...] (user code)
          return False
```

Comment: Raising a `TypeError` would probably be better

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but reading the documentation, `TypeError` is right: *"This exception may be raised by user code to indicate that an attempted operation on an object is not supported, and is not meant to be. ... Passing arguments of the wrong type (e.g. passing a list when an int is expected) should result in a TypeError"*